# Gestures and color drawing

Tags: android

I am detecting gestures on one of my activities - I am using it to navigate through photos. Every time I am doing a gesture, yellow line is being drawn on the screen. Is there any way to set [GestureColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html#attr_android:gestureColor) as transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write the color in the form of "#aarrggbb", then 'aa' represent the transparency. Thus the color #00000000 is completely transparent.

Comment: Thanks for this info.. but when I drag, it will first display a yellow color for 1 second, then it become transparent. How can I make it tranparent from the beginning itself..?

Comment: Late but... Put the same color in android:uncertainGestureColor