# Android : gesture color

Tags: android, gesture

I want to remove the gesture color (yellow).

I got a code from the  [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206211/gestures-and-color-drawing) , but I am facing some problem with this answer. When I begin to drag, the gesture is appearing with yellow color for 1 second, and then it become transparent.

How can I make it completely transaparent fro  the beginning itself..?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

As said by Nuktu, you can use the below attribute in case of uncertain gesture.
`android:uncertainGestureColor="#000"`

in case of certain gesture the system will take the color value from the following attribute.
`android:gestureColor="#000"`

One more thing, color value should be always kept as the background color then only the gesture wouldn't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file of the `GestureOverlay`, you can set that initial color of a stroke by using: `android:uncertainGestureColor="#000"`

This determines the color used to draw the user's strokes until we are sure it's a gesture.

More information [here](http://Color%20used%20to%20draw%20the%20user%27s%20strokes%20until%20we%20are%20sure%20it%27s%20a%20gesture.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set both **gestureColor** and **uncertainGestureColor** to **transparent** or **#000** in your code or xml to attain what you want cause at the beginning it takes the gesture as uncertain.......

Answer (score 0):

To remove yellow swiping bar permanantly,set gesture visibility to false.

```
mGestureOverlayView=new GestureOverlayView(this);
    mGestureOverlayView.setGestureVisible(false);
     View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home_application_screen, null);
        mGestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
```